# what is the different between 文言 and 书面？

Tags: grammar

[image]
I have check the A Chinese-English dictionary which doesn’t have the translation to English in register content and I come across 文言 and 书面.
what is the different between 文言 and 书面？

Answer (score 2):

文言 refers to the written language commonly used before 4th May 1919. (文言: 指五四以前通用的以古汉语为基础的书面语。)

In the dictionary you cited, 书面 thus refers to the modern written language.

Comment: And what is the difference between 古语 vs 旧称?

Comment: 古语 an old saying; 旧称 what something used to be called.

Comment: @monalisa Do you mean in Classical Chinese? I am confusing

Comment: However, I am still confused with the different between 书面， 文言，古语 and 旧称.

Comment: @IEatMyPizza not sure about your confusion. It's pretty clear that 书面 is written language and 文言 is the old ancient language. The words have expressed themselves. It's pretty literal. 古语 is 古代用语 and 旧称 is 旧时的称谓.

Comment: @IEatMyPizza The words "古语" and "旧称" can be used in modern writing as well, as in 這是一句古語，and 中山的旧称是香山。

Answer (score 0):

书面语言是指用文字的方式表达自己的情感或者想要描述的画面，在汉语中，古代的书面语言叫做文言文，现代的书面语言叫做白话文。

Answer (score 0):

书面语 -> words you write down, like words in articles, magazines, etc.

口语 -> words you say, like words you use when chatting with your friends.

Just think about English. English also has written language (书面语) and Spoken language (口语). 书面语 is more accurate than 口语，because you take lots of time to write it and you also check it out several times after finishing it.

文言文 -> words ancient people write down

古语 -> words ancient people write down and say

旧称 -> the way ancient people call a thing. The same thing can have different names in ancient and modern.

These are some simple definitions I can think of. Hope it can help you.